# frame doesnt changes while orientation in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, orientation, frame

In my root view controller's viewDidLoad, i added an observer for orientation detection:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Added the method like:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSLog(@"%f,%f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

I was expecting the result 768,1004 for the portrait and 1004,768 for the landscape. But my result is 768,1004 for the both. sometimes it will be 748,1024 for the portrait. I dont know why this strange behaviour. If you know the solution please help me.

**EDIT**
This same code works in my another project and i couldnt find any difference between them

Answer (score 1):

Add these two methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
      return TRUE;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

And do all modifications here:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)  interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
     NSLog(@"%f,%f",self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[If you look at Apple's documentation for `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, it says]:

> Sent to the view controller just before the user interface begins
>   rotating.

This means the frame width & height should be for the orientation *before* rotating.

Perhaps if you try to get the frame coordinates after the rotation is done, say, during [`didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation%3a), you might see something more like what you were hoping to accomplish.

Comment: same result for didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation also

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need to add an observer for that notification, view controllers are sent this notification by default. So, remove those first two lines, and it should work properly. And since this is the "will" method, properly means you get the size of the view before the rotation.

However, the method, willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, does give you the dimensions of the view after the rotation if that's what you want (even though it's a "will" method).

**After Edit**

For some reason these methods work correctly for a controller embedded in a navigation controller, but not for a single controller, or a modal controller. For those situations, switching from bounds from frame, fixed the problem.

Comment: @manujmv, hmmm... don't know how that can be. It works fine for me. You've removed the addObserver line?

Comment: @manujmv, OK, I just confirmed your result. I was testing in an iPhone app, not iPad. I get the same results as you there. to fix it, change frame to bounds.

Comment: Thanks for ur help.but now i get the correct size with bounds in my root view controller. but in my inner screens, the same result obtained. one more thing, in my another project, i used the frame but it works correctly and it is also an ipad.

Comment: @manujmv, what do you mean "inner screens"? Are you logging them too? If so, how and where do you do that?

Comment: i mean screens after navigation. in there, i get the incorrect result with both frame and bounds

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34669/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-manujmv)