# iOS Cocoa UITableView position after rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I can use this code to position a UITableView wherever I want it:

```
CGRect newFrame = self.aTableView.frame;
newFrame.size.height = 300.0;
newFrame.size.width = 300.0;
newFrame.origin.y = 400;
newFrame.origin.x = 400;
self.aTableView.frame = newFrame;
```

The above code works fine. BUT when I then rotate the table view using the following code, it always gets positioned at (0,0) in other words, the top left of the screen:

```
CGPoint oldCenter=self.aTableView.center;
self.aTableView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
self.aTableView.center=oldCenter;
```

How can I position a table once I rotate it?

Thank you very much for any insight you may be able to provide.

Comment: Note: The 'CGPoint oldCenter=self.aTableView.center;' and 'self.aTableView.center=oldCenter;' lines can be removed and the result does not change. The table still goes to the top left of the screen.

Comment: Handle Orientation. set Correct AutoLayout constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was being caused by not properly detecting the iPhone's rotation. In other words:
• the code for rotating the table was fine
• merely rotating the table did not cause it to disappear
The problem was that I was not properly detecting the iPhone's rotation. Rather than detail the wrong methods I used, I will simply share what worked for XCode 5 / iOS 7.

Here is what worked:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
     {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)  interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    //This is where I now place the code to rotate the table
    //I test interfaceOrientation to see the current orientation
    NSLog(@"%d", interfaceOrientation);
}
```

By using this method of detecting phone rotation, my code to change the frame of the UITableView worked every time.
Mainly based on:
[frame doesnt changes while orientation in ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008877/frame-doesnt-changes-while-orientation-in-ipad?rq=1)